# Парсинг .docx файлов python

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Как можно узнать какой тип шрифта слова используется  в `.doc` файле

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('2.docx')
for para in document.paragraphs:
    para.text
```

Но по сути он выводит сплошной текст из дока

По сути мне нужно чтобы вы выводе текст писало что то вроде

**Hello** - Этот текст жирный
*world* - это курсивный
ну если еще вариант с картинкой то это вообще будет шикарно( что если в тексте есть картинка то выводило что то вроде - это картинка)

может есть какая то функция в `docx`, но к сожаления я не знаю как ее на практике реализовать

Comment: по сути сам формат docx уже описывает, где жирный, где курсивный, где картинка итд (архив с xml). Вы какой-то свой формат хотите придумать для передачи той же информации?

Comment: @jfs мне нужно чтобы просто чтобы при нахождение допустим жирного текста в файле он выводил что вот данный текст жирный.

Comment: попробуйте распаковать docx файл как zip архив (можете переименовать расширение в `.zip` и прямо в explorer как в папку зайти), там вы найдёте xml файл, который явно показывает *"вот данный текст жирный"* Если вам вся информация из docx не нужна, тогда вопрос что выкинуть, что оставить и в каком конкретно формате вы хотите оставшуюся информацию сохранить?

Comment: @jfs  Ну по сути мне нужно искать в тексте жирное слово и добавлять его в базу данных в один столбец, а курсивное слово в другой

Comment: тогда просто `for r in para.runs(): if r.font.bold: #жирный` Проверьте отражает ли это наследуемые стили. В сторону: я не понимаю, что значит добавить в один столбец, другой (я таблицу в бд построчно представляю: можно добавить/удалить строку целиком)

Comment: @jfs Да это именно то что нужно

Comment: если думаете, что нашли решение, опубликуйте его как свой ответ на будущее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @jfs по сути то это вашь ответ на мой вопрос) Разве не так?

Comment: вы запустите, убедитесь что работает и минимальный пример кода (для понимания) в ответ добавьте.  Мой опыт работы с Word форматами говорит, что ничего достаточно сложное не работает для всех документов на нескольких версиях (всегда проблемы). Но иногда для некоторых документов, созданных в некоторых версиях Word может работать -- что может быть достаточно в вашем случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать функцию `runs` после чего сортировать список по типу шрифта `bold` жирный `italic` курсивный:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('Иван.docx')
for para in document.paragraphs:

    for r in para.runs:
        if r.font.bold:
            print(r.text)
        if r.font.italic:
            print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Данный код выводит индексы всех параграфов и сообщает о наличии картинки в самом параграфе:

```
for index, prgh in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
    print(index)
    if 'Graphic' in prgh._p.xml:
        print('в этом параграфе есть картинка')
```